# Tab key listener in jadf

Tags: java, oracle-adf

While entering a value in ADF table if tab is pressed the cursor goes to the next row but the row focus do not changes. In other words, ADF allows to make entry in a row other than the focused or current row.

How can I make the row marked as current in which I am changing the value but do not have row focus?

Answer (score 0):

Set `editingMode="clickToEdit"` in your table